# Cordova barcode plugin scan not returning to Android app page

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, qr-code

When I am scanning a barcode in my Android Cordova project, I am using the following code:

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
     function (result) {

         myXMLString = result.text;

         if (result != null){

         document.location.href = "MyPage.html";

         }

     },
     function (error) {
         alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
     }
  );
```

However, when I run the app on the device, the scan completes and I get the message

```
Application Error

net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///android_asset/www/MyPage.html
```

The console log shows:
    E/AndroidProtocolHandler: Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/MyPage.html

How do I fix this? I have this file in assets/www folder in my Android Studio project. It works on Windows and iOS Platforms.

Comment: Do you have MyPage.html in your project's root (www) folder??

Comment: I have it here: MyProject/platforms/android/assets/www

Comment: I m asking about your project structure outside platforms folder

Comment: Yes, it is present there also, when I build from Android Studio I usually edit the files in assets/www and later on copy them into the main project structure outside the platforms folder. Should I rebuild using `cordova build android` ? Doesn't the error indicate that it is looking for the file inside android_asset/www?